DS160 form filled for one country but scheduled visa interview in another country
I have submitted my DS160 form with consulate given as Hyderabad, India. However, I am unable to make that trip to India, and I will be going to Ottawa, Canada for my H1b stamping. Can I use the same DS160 form as all the details/ info is the same except for the consulate location I chose towards the end.
